# Speed up one-frame rendering in blender

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

I'm trying to render a single frame of a t-shirt model. But, it seems to be too slow, even with GPU rendering (Nvideo M2000).

Here is link to my [.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51747) file.

Here is my configuration and the source code to compute the rendering time:
[image]

Could you please tell me some tips to speed up the rendering time? or 13s is normal for this task?

Comment: There is no "normal". Each scene renders differently. It all depends on the complexity of the scene: the number of vertices/edges/faces (unfortunately you cut out that information on the image you posted), render settings, modifiers (invisible on the image as well), use of simulations, particles (again we can't guess from the picture), render size, number of samples, etc. All of that plus the computing power of your platform, number of cores, available RAM (we don't know that information either),   other processes running simultaneously, etc, etc.... Rendering takes time, period.

Comment: Questions like this get asked all the time, please use the search box at the top to browse through the many posts about this same topic.

Comment: Hi @cegaton, Sorry for missing the blend file. I understand that rendering takes time, but I don't know how GPU rendering is slower than CPU in a same computer. I have updated the question with my blend file and computer specs.

Comment: Again, it depends on what kind of hardware you are using, and the complexity of the scene and render settings. https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=render+speed and https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=render+speed+gpu and https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=render+optimize